# android progressbar

Tags: android

как можно сделать, чтобы во время progressbar пользователь не мог нажимать на элементы на экране? 
Как в progressDialog(который устарел)

Comment: Он потому и устарел, что такой подход не рекомендуется. Но вывести диалог и вставить в него прогрессбар Вам никто не помешает, как и с любой другой разметкой https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=ru#CustomLayout

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте ваш бар во `FrameLayout`, который имеет размеры родителя (match_parent), добавьте `Frame` в корневой `Layout` (`Frame`  или `Relative`) и пропишите атрибут `clickable=false`.

Показывайте `FrameLayout`, когда надо показывать прогрессбар.

Для эффекта затенения можно использовать во фрэйме атрибут `background="#5000"`.